# the playerMotor script for my fps game isnt working

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCRxx.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhv31.png)

i tried following the tutorial and copied everything to perfection

Comment: Which tutorial? Seems like a lot is missing a lot in there!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add codes as text in the questions/answers please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)